# What is the gnome-terminal ANSI escape sequence for "CTRL + arrow/s"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, gnome-terminal, escape-characters

I am trying to configure my bash `~/.inputrc` to these settings
(Note: <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd> mean the left and right arrow keys)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> - should jump back a word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> - should jump forward a word

Currently I have this in my `~/.inputrc` and it doesn't work. <kbd>Ctrl + arrow</kbd> produces nothing.

```
"\eC-5C":forward-word
"\eC-5D":backward-word
```

I'm sure my escape sequence is wrong.
What are the correct escape sequences for the <kbd>Ctrl + arrow</kbd> combinations?

- terminal: tmux inside gnome-terminal

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gnome-terminal (more properly *VTE*) imitates some version of xterm's escape sequences.  How closely it does this, depends on the version of VTE.

The relevant xterm documentation is in the [PC-Style Function Keys](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys) section of [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).

What you are looking for is a string like `\e[1;5D` (for control left-arrow), where the `5` denotes the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier.

In ncurses, you can see these strings using `infocmp -x`, as the values for `kUP5`, `kDN5`, `kLFT5` and `kRIT5`.  For example:

```
    kDN5=\E[1;5B,
    kLFT5=\E[1;5D,
    kRIT5=\E[1;5C,        
    kUP5=\E[1;5A,
```

Comment: thanks for response and link to resources.  This solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 21):

The simplest way to find what are the codes of a key sequence is to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd>.

So, you type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> to get:

```
^[[1;5C
```

Which is a way to write `ESC[1;5C` or `\e[1;5C`.

Comment: wow, cool. do you know if that an intended feature of gnome-terminal, or is it something that was discovered by accident?

Comment: Both zsh (`bindkey|grep 'quoted-insert'`) and bash (`bind -p|grep 'quoted-insert'`) have a key binding to output the key codes set to `<c-v>`.

Comment: @the_velour_fog No, no accident. Those are codes used by xterm. The actual definition of [all the codes is quite long](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). Your head will spin if you try to understand it all. :-) ...... Wikipedia also has a good page about ANSI codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: For what it's worth, Ctrl-V performs the same function in Vim's Insert and Command modes.

Comment: @the_velour_fog Ctrl+V meaning “insert the next character instead of interpreting it as a terminal command” dates back from the early days of Unix. It's a feature of the kernel's command line processing that's been imitated by more sophisticated input systems such as bash, zsh, vi, ...

Comment: @kba For the record, they're not the only ones. Bash's is actually provided by the GNU Readline library it depends on, which also binds it to `<c-q>` to match Emacs keybind it's copying. Zsh also binds it to both `<c-v>` and `<c-q>` but only if you enable Vim mode, ironically enough. Readline is also used by other things like Python's `import rlcompleter` enhancement. (Sources: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9 and `man zshzle`)